# Pivot table error - type mismatch

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a pivot table but it throws out the following error - "Runtime error 13 - Type mismatch". When i run the code through the lines, the error lands on the final line with the "activeworkbook.pivotcaches.etc..."

```
Sub testmodule()

Dim wsA, wsB As Worksheet

Set wsA = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set wsB = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pivot Tables")


Set rnge = wsA.Range("B6")
Set rngData = Range(rnge, rnge.End(xlToRight))
Set rngData = Range(rnge, rnge.End(xlDown))
Set rngB = wsB.Range("C8")

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngData, _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=rngB, _
    TableName:="pvtReportA_B", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14

End Sub
```

Can anyone advise where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Change ...`PivotCaches.Create`... to ...`PivotCaches.Add`...

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngData, _
    Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=rngB, _
    TableName:="pvtReportA_B", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

[Here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174270%28v=office.11%29.aspx) the link to the PivotCaches object on Microsoft Dev Center.  It uses the Add method instead of Create (but your syntax was correct.)